# Increasing number of connections allowed by R

Tags: linux, r

I have been struggling with establishing a 5 node, 200 CPU cluster mainly because R apparently has NCONNECTIONS set to limit the max to 128. According to what I've read [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-hpc/2012-May/001373.html), I need to change the parm and rebuild R (presumably on every node?), but I cannot find the directory or file specified above.

How do I change NCONNECTIONS and rebuild R?

I am running Linux version 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64

Comment: I think this implies you're using a socket-based, snow-like cluster, but: (a) for a single CPU with lots of cores you'd rather use parallel::mclapply and friends, as these do not spawn separate instances of R and so are more memory efficient, and tend to be easier to manage; and (b) Rmpi will generally be a better bet, e.g., with communication costs (movement of data to / from nodes) scaling with the log of the number of nodes, rather than linearly, and not consuming R's sockets!.

Comment: @MartinMorgan You're correct, but I think we're using terminology differently -- I have 5 machines each with 40 processors and am trying to run an extremely large number of very small jobs that do not need parallelism (can run independently). What do you recommend for such a problem?

Comment: If you use snow rather than parallel, you can create the cluster using makeMPIcluster rather than makePSOCKcluster to avoid the socket connection limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the post you provide a link to, we read "You would have to rebuild R after increasing NCONNECTIONS in src/main/connections.c". I guess this is a file in the source tree of R, so you first have to download that source tree, for instance under any Debian-based distrib:

```
$ apt-get source r-base
```

Then do the alteration and compile (`./configure ; make ; make install` from the `r-base-3.1.1` directory that has been created in your current directory).

Comment: I'm far from an expert on clusters, so let me ask: would it make sense to stick with the 128-connection limit and write a wrapper which divides the work across two top-level instances of `R`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short function

```
FUN <- function(i) { Sys.sleep(1); paste("job", i) }
```

Load the snow library and spawn a connection to each machine in the cluster

```
library(snow)
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(5)
```

then for each machine do the work using parallel::mclapply, using all the cores available.

```
parLapply(cl, seq_along(cl), function(i, FUN, n, ...) {
    parallel::mclapply(seq_len(n), FUN, ...)
}, FUN, 8, mc.cores=parallel::detectCores())
```

clean up when done

```
stopCluster(cl)
```

Here's the same strategy, a little bit more cryptically and using `snow::splitList` (or `splitIndicies`) to divide tasks into those done by each member of the snow cluster.

```
library(snow)
library(parallel)

tasks <- splitList(1:40, length(cl))
parLapply(cl, tasks, mclapply, FUN, mc.cores=detectCores())
```

It's a shame that there isn't a default way of doing this; the [BiocParallel](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/BiocParallel.html) package allows

```
library(BiocParallel)

register(MulticoreParam())  ## 'inner' worker
register(SnowParam(4))      ## outer worker; 'register' is a stack

bplapply(1:4, function(i, FUN, n) {
    result <- BiocParallel::bplapply(seq_len(n), FUN)
    sprintf("%d:%d", i, unlist(result))
}, FUN, 8)
```

Comment: Guess that answers my question under jaybees' response. Thanks